# How to pass predefined_acl in GCS blob's rewrite method

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-client, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to copy file from one bucket to another bucket in GCS. Source file is public however copied file is staying private. I want to make it public. I am using GCS blob's `rewrite` method where I could not find option to pass `predefined_acl` compare to `upload_from_filename` which I use to upload file and make it public.

Here's the pseudo-code I am using to copy

```
source_blob = bucket.blob(source_path)
destination_blob = bucket.blob(destination_path)
destination_blob.rewrite(source_blob)
```

Is there any way to pass `predefined_acl` in-case of rewrite function ?

GCS blob's `rewrite` function documentation - https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_rewrite

GCS blob's `upload_from_filename` function documentation - https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_upload_from_filename

Comment: Yes, it is possible to specify the predefined_acl while using the `rewrite` method in GCS. You can pass the `predefined_acl` parameter as a string to the `destination_blob.rewrite` method, with one of the following predefined ACLs: private, `publicRead`, `authenticatedRead`, `bucketOwnerRead`, or `bucketOwnerFullControl`. This will allow you to copy a file from one bucket to another and set its permissions to be public or private, as desired.

Comment: @Chanpols I could not find`predefined_acl` in the GCS documentation for `rewrite` function
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_rewrite